# How to position text over Font Awesome icon?

Tags: css, font-awesome

Is there a way to vertically align text stacked on top of a Font Awesome icon? I'd like to move the #1 up in this stack so that it is centered in the cup of the trophy icon. I tried adding bottom-margin and bottom-padding in the span that encapsulates the #1, but neither one did the trick. Is there an easy way to do what I'm trying to accomplish, or do I need to go another route?

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
  <i class="fa fa-trophy fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <span class="fa fa-stack-1x" style="color:red;">
    <span style="font-size:35px;">
      #1
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wc2jP/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add `display:block; margin-top:-20px;` to the #1 `<span>` tag like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/wc2jP/1/

Comment: You are awesome. It was driving me crazy. Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 5):

A couple of months after you asked this question, the team at Font Awesome blogged about this with examples using their calendar, comment, and file icons:  [Stacking Text and Icons](http://blog.fontawesome.io/2014/05/19/stacking-text-and-icons/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `line-height` property as well with `display:inline-block`.

```
span{
vertical-align:top; 
display:inline-block; 
line-height:1.6em;
}
```

Here is the Working ***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wc2jP/)***.