# Style font over fontawesome icon

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome, webfonts

Building on this post... [Font over font awesome icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644741/how-to-position-text-over-font-awesome-icon)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wc2jP/1/)

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
<i class="fa fa-trophy fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <span class="fa fa-stack-1x" style="color:red;">
      <span style="font-size:35px; margin-top:-20px; display:block;">
          #1
      </span>
</span>
```

I want the "1" inside the trophy to look like this...❶ ... its a "1" inside a black circle, similar like a numbered billiard ball and I want to be able to CSS style it, color, size, border, etc. Is that possible to achieve? This ❶ is a symbol I copied from Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
    <i class="fa fa-trophy fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <span class="fa fa-stack-1x" style="color:red;">
          <span>
              #1
          </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fa-trophy ~ .fa{font-size:35px;margin-top:13px;display:block;position:relative}
.fa-trophy ~ .fa span{background:#fff;color:red;border-radius:50%;width:24px;height:24px;text-align:center;font-size:20px;line-height:20px;display:block;padding:4px;position:absolute;top:16%;left:0;right:0;margin:auto}
```

Let me know if that's along the lines of what you had in mind.

Comment: My idea was to have the Font Awesome TROPHY and inside that trophy to have the "1" as I specified.

Comment: I can get the billiard ball done but I cannot get it to center inside the TROPHY horizontally and vertically.